# Custom table / Alternative to WP_List_Table

Tags: plugin-development

I am developing a plugin that make use of WP_List_Table to display logs and some other content in the admin.

WP_List_Table works fine to display content but i need now to create a table that works on a custom db table and that allows new/edit actions on data.

I've noticed is a bit tricky handle edit/new forms actions with WP_List_Table and were looking for alternatives, frameworks or what so ever that could offer these basic features.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [**WP Basic Crud**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-basic-crud/) plugin made by [Labarta](https://labarta.es/).

Users may add a new contact, edit it, and view the list table.

[image]

[image]

The plugin creates a table named **wp_cte** when it is being activated.

[image]